# Cannot export symbols to Excel from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

i am exporting gridview to excel,i am exporting successfully.but in my gridview i have some special symbols like ( •, "", ', -,_ ) these types of symbols cannot export, instead of those place i am getting like ( â€“, â€œ, â€, â€™)this.
how can i over come these problem. here is my code for exporting gridview to excel ?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;          
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=demo.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvDetails.AllowPaging = false;
gvDetails.DataSource = dt1;
gvDetails.DataBind();
for (int i = 0; i < gvDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvDetails.Rows[i];            
    row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
}
gvDetails.RenderControl(hw);
//style to format numbers to string
string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify and provide encoding information.

`Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; /*c# uses UTF-16 internally*/`
...
`Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble()); /*Include the UTF-16 header so excel will treat this as UTF-16*/
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());`
...

Note that this is not the best solution, ideally you should use OpenXML or some other library to export to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your content type to below,

```
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
```